# want to put javascript code in while loop so that when cphealth or player health is <= 0 the game stops

Tags: javascript, while-loop

i am wanting to put a while loop somewhere so the games stops when either you or the computer have 0 or less health and display a message after that saying somebody won but no matter how i try or where i put them i can never seem to get a while loop to work. Please help me :)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var health = 100;
    var cphealth = 100;
    var lightAttacks = -20;
    var block = 10;
    var Ties = 0;

    function randomGen() {
        var max = 3;
        var min = 1;
        var answer = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
        return answer;
        //sets up the random number generator
    }
    var name = "";
    var userChoice = "";
    var compChoice = 99;
    $("#lightAttack").click(function() {
        userChoice = "lightAttack"
        compChoice = randomGen();
        whoWon(userChoice, compChoice);
    });
    $("#block").click(function() {
        userChoice = "block"
        compChoice = randomGen();
        whoWon(userChoice, compChoice);
    });
    $("#heal").click(function() {
        userChoice = "heal"
        compChoice = randomGen();
        whoWon(userChoice, compChoice);
        //sets up the random number generator
    });

    function whoWon(user, comp) {
        var winnerMessage = "ERROR";
        if (user == 'lightAttack') {
            if (comp == 1) { //developer says 1 = attack back
                winnerMessage = "Computer attacked back";
                (health = health + lightAttacks) && (cphealth = cphealth + lightAttacks)
            } else if (comp == 2) { //developer says 2 = block next attack
                winnerMessage = "Computer blocked your attack and reflected some damage";
                health = health - 5
            } else { //developer says 3 = heal and its just else 1 or 2 ot must be 3
                winnerMessage = "Computer heals back part of your attack damage";
                cphealth = cphealth - 10
            }
        }
        if (user == 'block') {
            if (comp == 1) { //developer says 1 = lightAttack
                winnerMessage = "You blocked the computer attack and reflected some damage";
                cphealth = cphealth - 5
            } else if (comp == 2) { //developer says 2 = block
                winnerMessage = "Nothing happened because you both blocked";
                health = health + 0
            } else { //developer says 3 = heal and if its not 1 or 2 ot must be 3
                winnerMessage = "Computer heals 10 health";
                cphealth = cphealth + 10
            }
            //sets up the results for if the user picks block
        }
        if (user == 'heal') {
            if (comp == 1) { //developer says 1 = lightAttack
                winnerMessage = "Computer attacked";
                health = health - 10
            } else if (comp == 2) { //developer says 2 = block
                winnerMessage = "Computer blocked";
                health = health + 10
            } else { //developer says 3 = heal and if its not 1 or 2 ot must be 3
                winnerMessage = "You both picked heal";
                health = health + 10;
                cphealth = cphealth + 10;
            }
        }
        if (comphealth <= 0) {
            alert("You Win!")
        }
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = winnerMessage;
        document.getElementById("myhealth").innerHTML = health;
        document.getElementById("comphealth").innerHTML = cphealth;
    }
});
```

Comment: You have no while loop in your code, and it works perfectly, you don't need to add one. You several options: (1) Remove all the listeners from the buttons. This is the simplest. (2) Check if you won before each function call/event listener

Answer (score 1):

If you try using a while loop in Javascript for this your program will get stuck in the while loop forever. Javascript has a single thread of execution so there is no way to run your while loop in parallel with the rest of the game.

One thing you could consider doing instead is to structure your game logic in "turns". Every turn you apply changes to the game state (player moves around a bit, takes damage, deals damage, etc) and at the end of the turn you check to see if their health dropped to zero.

Comment: Thank you very much good sir but seeing as this project is due soon so I probably don't have time do do this